# Rails returns a nil, when searching with find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find

I'm beginning to learn RoR, but i've a problem which i don't understand. With Product.find :all returns all the records from DB. But if i want to find_by_gender(1) (or even 2) it returns a nil, i'm certain that the db contains products with a gender

My code controller:

> gender = params[:gender].to_i
>
> @search_results = Product.find_by_gender(gender)

this returns a nill,

What am i doing wrong?

Greetings!

Comment: Show your table description and actual data.

Comment: If you try `Product.find_by_gender(1)` in the Rails console, does it return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your data first!
Look at some sample records:
Do something like:

```
Product.all(:limit => 5).each {|product| product.id.to_s + product.gender}
```

or go into sql

`sql>  select id, gender from products where id < 6;`

If you are to verify what the gender values are you can then create named scopes in your model for those conditions, e.g. (rails3)
(Product Model - `app/models/product.rb`)

```
scope :male where(:gender) = male_value # i.e. 1 or 'M' or 'Male' or whatever
scope :female where(:gender) = female_value # i.e. '2' or 'F' or whatever
```

Which will then you let write `Products.male` or `Products.female` !

Final note - should gender be in your users table? , or is this for male / female specific products?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the solution to my problem was the create form. This didn't get all the input correct. Thank to your answer i looked at it again.

Also looked to scopes, it is now warking like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`find_by_...` returns either first record or `nil` if none found, `find_all_by_...` returns all records that match (or empty array if none). In your case `nil` means no records found with gender = 1.

Answer (score 1):

in rails console execute

```
Product.pluck(:gender)
```

And u will know that values does it have in AR(i think true and false), so u have to use query `Product.find_by_gender(true)`

Comment: That would depend on how he's storing `gender` in the database. It seems that he's storing it as an integer, not a boolean.